# Access azure pipeline artifact using Azure CLI shows error: "TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as ..."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-authentication

I have created a service principal using Azure CLI (Command: az ad sp create-for-rbac --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID). I have written a script which used service principal for login and use "az pipelines" command to download artifact from pipeline. If I run the script, I get an error "TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as .... in a web browser to enable access to the service". Can you help us to know why this error happens and a way to solve this issue.

If the script is run on a machine in which azure login is done before (Using PAT token) then the script is working fine without any error.

##### PowerShell  script

```
az devops configure --defaults organization=$ORGANIZATION 
az devops configure --defaults project=$PROJECT_NAME 
az login --service-principal --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --tenant TENANT #login 
$BuildList=az pipelines build list --branch $BRANCH_NAME --result "succeeded" --top 1
```

Comment: Can you share the script. It sounds like you're not logging in properly in the script, but hard to provide an answer without seeing it.

Comment: @GordonBy
Power shell Script:
.....
az devops configure --defaults organization=$ORGANIZATION
az devops configure --defaults project=$PROJECT_NAME
az login --service-principal --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --tenant TENANT #login
$BuildList=az pipelines build list --branch $BRANCH_NAME --result "succeeded" --top 1
......
 Get last build id and prints it

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#user-prompted-to-use-az-devops-login) then there's an important note;

> If you have already signed in with az login interactively or if you're using a user name and password, you're not required to provide a token because the az devops commands now support sign-in through az login. **However, you can't sign in as the service principal via az login**. In that scenario, a PAT is required.

You should therefore drop the az login command and use az devops login providing a PAT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#pipe-pat-on-stdin-to-az-devops-login